# what is Two-sided p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, t-test, p-value

I was reading documentation about linregress method of scipy.stats, and in the part where it discusses the results, it mentions something called Two-sided p-value. I couldn't understand what that is. I know what p-value is and how it is calculated but I never heard of two-sided p-value. Can someone explain what that refers to?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a one-sided hypothesis test and a two-sided hypothesis test?

Answer (score 1):

A p value from a two sided test is the probability that the test statistic is at least as large as the observed test statistic *in absolute value*, assuming the assumptions of the test are well satisfied.

Graphically, it is the shaded region in this plot

[image]